# Why isn't my Empire heater getting any gas?

Tags: gas, heater

My Empire heater does not seem to be receiving any gas when I turn or press the pilot knob. I believe the gas is supposed to flow when you press the pilot knob to light the heater but nothing comes out. All the gas faucets are turned on.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a clogged orifice, do you have a drip leg on the gas line?

Comment: I haven't checked the tubes yet, maybe they are clogged. And I don't think there is a drip leg.

Comment: Look at the gas line feeding the heater, is there an extra bit of pipe off a tee with a cap on it before the line enters the heater?  If so, this is a drip leg. [Drip leg example](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9o-PSMIsrqWdxKIBSBzm9T0dLfbFdV9U5FMd0GFPiWL7FLMF07A)

Comment: @Tester101 I don't think it has a drip leg. Do you think I should take the pipe off and clean it out?

Comment: Do you have a shutoff valve nearby?  How much experience do you have working with gas lines? Do you have a model number for the heater?

Comment: The pipe itself is likely clean, since it's probably 1/2". The problem is, the orifice on the pilot assembly is really small.  Any small bit of debris in the line can clog it.  Normally there will be a drip leg, which allows any crap in the line to fall harmlessly into it.

Comment: @Tester101, It doesn't have a drip leg, what do you suggest I do? I have never worked with gas lines before but I can take stuff apart ;)

Comment: Call an HVAC tech. Gas lines are not something you should be working on if you don't know what you're doing.  This is one of those things that is better left to a trained professional, especially since it could lead to an exploding house.

Comment: I'm not going to pay $100/hr for someone to come and look at it. Although I haven't done gas pipes before I do know how they work.

Comment: I think $100/hr is much cheaper than an exploded house, but I could be wrong. There is a reason things like this are so expensive.

Comment: You may be able to remove the pilot tube to gain access to the orifice (so you can clean it), but it would depend on the pilot assembly. Do you have the model number of the heater?

Comment: Empire DV-215. I took the pipe off that goes to the heater and it's getting gas. I will take a look at the orifice soon.

Comment: HVAC guy came by and changed the pipes and fixed it. I don't know what the problem was.